# Why is backbone sending model information inside {model: {model_property:value ,...} } when i save a model

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js, mongoose

I'm writing an app with node.js and backbone.js. However when I try to save a model it is nesting the JSON of the model inside a model dictionary.

```
node = new NodeModel({prop1:"value1", prop2:"value2"});
node.save();
```

The results of console.log(req.body); inside my node controler show...

```
{model: {"prop1":"value1", "prop2":"value2"} }
```

If i use a standard html form to post to the same node controller the results of console.log(req.body); show...

```
{prop1:"value1", prop2:"value2"}
```

How can i get the node.save(); function to post the same JSON that the regular HTML does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have Backbone configured to [emulate JSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON):

> **emulateJSON** `Backbone.emulateJSON = true`
>
> If you're working with a legacy web server that can't handle requests encoded as `application/json`, setting `Backbone.emulateJSON = true;` will cause the JSON to be serialized under a `model` parameter, and the request to be made with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime type, as if from an HTML form.

and the corresponding chunk of `Backbone.sync` looks like this:

```
if (!options.data && model && (method == 'create' || method == 'update')) {
  params.contentType = 'application/json';
  params.data = JSON.stringify(model.toJSON());
}
//...
if (Backbone.emulateJSON) {
  params.contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  params.data = params.data ? {model: params.data} : {};
}
```

You can see the `model.toJSON()` call in the first `if`, the `model:` prefix comes in in the second `if`. You should be able to say

```
Backbone.emulateJSON = false;
```

somewhere in your application setup (after Backbone is loaded, before you try to sync anything) and the `model:` business will go away.

Comment: @alex: Making sense is over rated, except when it works. I learned that on Australia Day (which is sort of a big deal in Whistler).

Comment: @Mu The TELUS Winter Classic?