# Backbone Model Save: sending fields as "model" subobject

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, backbone-model

User Model

```
define(
  [
    'backbone'
  ],
  function (Backbone) {

    return Backbone.Model.extend({
      url: '/proxy.php/users.json',

      defaults: {
        'first_name': '',
        'last_name': '',
        'work_email': ''
      },

      validation: {
        first_name: {
          required: true,
          msg: 'Please enter a first name'
        },

        last_name: {
          required: true,
          msg: 'Please enter a last name'
        },

        work_email: {
          required: true,
          msg: 'Please enter a valid email'
        }
      }

    });
  }
);
```

View save data

```
  onSave: function (ev) {

    ev.preventDefault()

    var details = $('.edit-user-form').serializeObject()
    var object = new User()

    return object.save(details, {
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response, 'response')
      }
    })
  },
```

details =

```
{first_name: "", last_name: "", birthdate: "", job_title: "", job_start_date: ""…}
birthdate: ""
first_name: ""
job_probation_ends: ""
job_start_date: ""
job_title: ""
last_name: ""
personal_address: ""
personal_email: ""
personal_phone_number: ""
work_address: ""
work_email: ""
work_phone_number: ""
```

The problem, the request sent by Backbone sends Form Data as:

```
model:{"first_name":"","last_name":"","work_email":"","birthdate":"","job_title":"","job_start_date":"","job_probation_ends":"","work_address":"","work_phone_number":"","personal_email":"","personal_address":"","personal_phone_number":""}
```

Why is it making the attributes a sub object of model? I would like the attributes sent as the root.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is backbone sending model information inside {model: {model\_property:value ,...} } when i save a model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005812/why-is-backbone-sending-model-information-inside-model-model-propertyvalue)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the structure of the data you send to the server, then override the toJSON method for your model:

```
toJSON: function () {
    return { // structure the model as you wish here };
}
```